# Add new rows to key from a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, key, sql-server-2012, range

Hi I have a question how to expand my key coloumn with data between two coloumns

```
SELECT tt.Nr_V, 
       tt.journalnumber_end, 
       tt.journalnumerstart 
 FROM transactiontable tt 


 SalesTransaction 

 Nr_V    JournalnumberStart JournalNumberEnd 

 100       1001002             1003000

 101       1003001             1004000 etc..


 OutPutTable 

 Nr_V JournalNumber 

 100    1001002 

 100     1001003

 100     1001004

 etc..

 100     1003000 etc..



 101     1004000
```

Comment: which database are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTE recursion

here is an example

```
create table r ( id int, st int, ed int )
insert into r values( 1, 5,7), (2 ,8,12)

with nums as (
  select r.id , r.st no
  from r 
  union all
  select nums.id,nums.no +1 from nums join r   
  on r.id = nums.id and r.ed > no
)
select * from nums
order by id, no
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77a21/8

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found out that auto generate an Int from min start to max start in a while loop and the join on a between start and end - made it for me! Thanks for your help! I really like your guys help - but I found my own way. Hav a good day.